# why use putFloat(String key, float value), putInt(String key, int value) instead of overload put(...)

Tags: java, android, oop, coding-style, overloading

It is general question about programming good practices. I'm analyzing Android API's and found that many methods are not overloaded. For example, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) have many methods for storing different types of variables, Google use convention:

```
putFloat(String key, float value)
putInt(String key, int value)
```

instead of

```
put(String key, float value)
put(String key, int value)
```

Why? Second approach seams to be more OOP.

Comment: I think it's sort of related to performance as it's really important to consume the least possible resources when creating app for cell phones and devices like them.

Comment: I would guess readability. "Overloaded methods should be used sparingly, as they can make code much less readable." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: According to: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/method-overloading-vs-method-overriding.html, overloading in Java is resolved using static binding. So, like in C++ it doesn't increase resources consumptions in runtime.

Comment: You would have to ask the authors. @mok It has no effect whatsoever on performance or resource consumption.